# ¿Para qué sirve la clase Presentation al momento de crear una instancia de un formulario?

Tags: c#, windows-forms

He visto en un tutorial de **C#** que para crear una instancia a un formulario se usaba la clase `Presentation` así:

```
Presentation.Form1 oForm1 = new Presentation.Form1();
```

Sin embargo, sé que también se puede hacer sin usarla.

¿Cuál es la diferencia?

Gracias.

Comment: Estas seguro que `Presentation` es una clase? no sera el namespace? sabes lo que es el namespace no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Entiendo que `Presentation` no es una `class` sino el `namespace` dentro del cual se define el form

[espacio de nombres (Referencia de C#)](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/namespace)

Si revisas el codigo del form deberias ver algo como ser

```
namespace Presentation
{
    public class Form1 : Form 
    {
       //codigo del form
    }
}
```

Cuando instancias el form puede indicar o no el namespace segun utilices el `using`

Entonces si estas en otro form con un namespace diferente podrias usar

```
using Presentation;

namespace OtroNamespace
{
    public class Form2 : Form 
    {
        public void button1_Click(...){

           Form1 = new Form1();
           //resto codigo

        }
    }
}
```

como defines el namespace en el using no es necesario indicarlo cuando instancias el form

Comment: Tienes razón, era un namespace. Gracias por la respuesta.